# Java string.split() is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to use the split method over a string. This throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException and I have no clue why. I've tried many strings and many separators.

```
    String temp = "abcd&efgh&ijkl&mnop";
    String[] tempArr = temp.split("ijk");
```

This is the error log:

```
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lino/com.example.lino.LinesActivity}:    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.example.lino.LinesActivity.onCreate(LinesActivity.java:32)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-13 12:20:30.619: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  ... 11 more
```

### Edit

This is the entire class:

```
    package com.example.lino;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class LinesActivity extends Activity {

        TextView tvTitle;
        String bussinessId, bussinessTitle;
        String[] passedString;
        List<Line> linesList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.lines_layout);

            tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainTitle);

            Bundle passedBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            passedString = passedBundle.getString("BussinessName").split(":");

            bussinessId = passedString[0];
            bussinessTitle = passedString[1]; // THIS IS LINE 32, BUT IT'S WORKING WELL

            tvTitle.setText(bussinessTitle);

            try {
                String temp = "abcd&efgh&ijkl&mnop";
                String[] tempArr = temp.split("ijk");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That split will give you an array of length 2. How are you using it? And where?

Comment: Is your `split()` call actually line 32 in `LinesActivity`?

Comment: String temp = "abcd&efgh&ijkl&mnop";
        String[] tempArr = temp.split("ijk");
        for(int i=0; i< tempArr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tempArr[i]);
        }----This works fine. so you should check your other codes. And it will be good to see the code form where you are calling this function.

Comment: I've added the entire class to the post

Answer (score 4):

Running :

```
String temp = "abcd&efgh&ijkl&mnop";
String[] tempArr = temp.split("ijk");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempArr));
```

I get

```
[abcd&efgh&, l&mnop]
```

with no Exception.

In my editor line 32 is actually shown as:

```
bussinessId = passedString[0];
```

which would indicate that the first `String.split`:

```
passedString = passedBundle.getString("BussinessName").split(":");
```

was not what you had intended.

Check the content of `passedBundle.getString("BussinessName")` to see if it contains a `:` character.

Comment: You have nailed it.  The OP is misinterpreting the evidence.

Answer (score 3):

```
passedString = passedBundle.getString("BussinessName").split(":");
```

I guess your `passedBundle.getString("BussinessName").split(":");`

is returning `only one element` and you are trying to accessing the `second` element from the `passedString` by  using `bussinessTitle = passedString[1];`

before `fetching` the elements from the `passedString array` print the length of the `passedString` in your log or

```
System.out.println(passedString.length);
```

and before accessing the element from the passedString array it's better to put a condition

```
if(passedString.length>0)
{
bussinessId = passedString[0];
bussinessTitle = passedString[1]; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have given cannot throw an Exception and crash.

I guess you forgotten to copy the code Line 32 of LinesActivity as stated in the logcat.

I am pretty sure you are reading a non existent line of the Array: tempArr